# Expectation of product of variables problem

Tags: probability, statistics

A problem is asking to work out the total value of insurance claims made in a 400-day period. I am given that the expected value of any given claim is $£1000$. I am also given that the amount of claims made on a daily basis is binomially distributed with parameters $n=20000, p=\frac{1}{10000}$ (so the expected number of daily claims is $2$).

Am I forced to make the assumption that the value of a claim (call this $V_i$) is independent of the number of claims (call this $X_i$) here? If so then the expected value would just be $400\times2 \times1000 = £800000$ which is straightforward enough, but I feel like I am cutting corners by making that assumption. Then again I don't think I have enough information here to work out the expectation if $X_i$ and $V_i$ were dependent: I can't do it by summation, and because I can't get the covariance I can't use $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y) + Cov(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the covariance was not given, you have to make the natural assumption that the covariance is zero, i.e. the random variables are independent. You are not cutting corners; you are doing the only thing that can be done here.